# SOA service calling back a client

Tags: events, client-server, soa

This is more a theoretical question than a practical one, but given I undestand the principles of SOA I am still a bit unsure about if this can be applied to any app.

The usual example is where a client wants to know something from a server thus we implement a service that can provide that information given a client request, it can be stateless or statefull, etc.

But what happens when we want to be notified when something happens on the server, maybe we call a service to register a search and want to be notified when a new item arrives to the server that matches or search.
Of course that can be implemented using polling and leverage that using long timeouts, but I can not see a way in the usual protocols to receive events from the server without  making a call to ask.

If you can point me to an example, or tell me an architecture that could support then you have made my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered pub-sub (ie; WS-Eventing, WS-Notification)? These are the usual means to pushing "stuff" to interested consumers/subscribers.

Comment: Yes after posting this question I further investigated and found there are some concepts that allow this type of comunicaciont, dynamic services, pub-sub, SOA 2.0, etc. I have not seen a lot of implementations / examples of this, but in every case this always is thought for comunication between WS, not WS and Client, the events, pubs always are sent to other WS and thus increasing the complexity of and otherwise thin client, the difference of having a client that just orchestrates calls to different WS and one that must implement it's own ones is great.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a Publish-Subscribe design. If you are using WCF checkout Programming WCF by Juval Lowery. In the appdendix he shows how to build a Pub-Sub system that is actually fully Per-Call. It doesn't even rely on CallbackContracts and keeping long running Channels open and so doesn't require any reconnection logic when communication is broken...let alone the need for any polling.